# I can't load angular1 UIgrid if its inside a template of angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-grid

I can't seem to load UIGrid of angular1 if its inside the view of angular2.
Excample

```
Template: (Inside angular2 template)
   <div id="gridController" ng-app="demo.app" ng-controller="GridDemoController as demo" class="tableContainer">
    <div id="grid" ui-grid="demo.gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>
```

However if I move that code inside index.html its working fine. Hope someone can enlighten me how to display UIGrid inside a template of angular2.

Comment: anyone experienced this one?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix this, angularui grid uses angular1 framework that's why it won't run in the view of angular2 . To use the grid , though its a bit of a hack, just place it on the index.html and then include the necessary files it needs and then you can already manipulate it to whatever you want from the angular1 controller as it renders on HTML (index on this case).

Thanks,